# How do i read css property of any clicked element?

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to make a jquery color picker, it should read the background color of whatever element is clicked and return it in a .result div.

Problem: How do I describe "the currently clicked" element?

This is my code:

```
$("p").click(function () {
  var color = $("p").css("background-color");
  $(".result").html("That div is <span style='color:" +
                     color + ";'>" + color + "</span>.");
});
```

I want this to work for any element which is clicked, not only p. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(ev){
  var color = $(ev.target).css("background-color");   
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/9v2rA/

Comment: This should work in most cases, but not for elements who have their on click handler with a `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` inside - as those events wont propagate to the `document` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a color picker box which contains a few `p` elements representing each color so you dont need to dispatch all `click` events on ANY element. You can work with `p`s. You can use `this` to reference to currently clicked `p`:

```
var color = $(this).css("background-color");
```

So your code will be:

```
$("p").click(function () {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  $(".result").html("That div is <span style='color:" +
                     color + ";'>" + color + "</span>.");
});
```

And your HTML may be:

```
<div class="color-picker">
  <p style="background-color: #111;"></p>
  <p style="background-color: #333;"></p>
  <p style="background-color: #666;"></p>
  <p style="background-color: #999;"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This will pick the color of the `p` element.

Comment: @Aram Alipoor: and how it would help with 'any' element? You still need to bind this handler on each and every element on the page.

Comment: Well, the question clearly states: 'it should read the background color of whatever element is clicked' and '[...] not only p':).

Comment: @Yury Yes sorry my bad :) I tried to answer "How do I describe the currently clicked element?". I changed my my answer anyway ;)